# retain the values of data entry in a placeholder during postbacks

Tags: php, html

how to retain the values of data entry in a placeholder during postbacks

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?PHP $name;?>" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
```

when php found any error and post it back
The data entry are all gone, user have to re enter all the information again.

Answer (score 2):

What does `value="<?PHP $name;?>"` do?  Is this supposed to print the variable?  You would need to do this instead:

```
<?= $name; ?>
```

or

```
 <?php echo $name;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if empty($name){
$name='Enter Name';
} else {}?>

<input type="text" name="name" <?php echo $name;?> placeholder="Enter Name"/>
```

Comment: Wouldn't using `if empty($name)` be of better practice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?PHP echo empty($_POST['name'])?'Enter Name':$_POST['name'];?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP use your $_POST / $_GET variables to restore your user data:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= $_POST['name'] ?>" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
```

Where $_POST['name'] contains the data sent via a POST request from the form and 'name' is the name of your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

`<input type="text" name="name" value="<PHP if (isset($name)){ echo $name; }?>"placeholder="Enter Name"/>`

The isset will handle any undefined variable errors, if $name has not been piror to the submission

Comment: Can someone edit my post with correct formatting? (submitting from mobile)